# Figures caption

Tags: captions

I am using `\subfigure` package to place two figures side by side. The following are the code lines for this purpose.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\mbox{\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=2in]{Figure 2a.png}}\quad
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=2in]{Figure 2b.png} }}
\caption{FE model geometry and boundary conditions; (a) tension/compression, (b) simple shear} %\label{Fig. 2}
\end{figure}
```

The placement of figures (2a and 2b) are correct but with the caption of the figure `2a.png` and `2b.png` are appearing (before the caption) in the document. I tried many ways to remove them but havn't succeeded.

Yours valuable suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The subcaptions should go before `\includegraphics`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Please complete your code snippet to a full compilable document.  In particular include information about how you load the `subfigure` package, as this will affect the answer.

Comment: The way I understand it, you want to remove the subcaptions. However, your code snippet, when placed in a document loading just the necessary packages, produce no subcaption. So please do as Andrew suggested, and produce a complete, compilable example, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using `subfigure`, but either `subfig` or `subcaption`.

Here's the version for `subfig`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{Figure 2a.png}}\quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{Figure 2b.png}}

\caption{FE model geometry and boundary conditions; (a)~tension\slash compression,
(b)~simple shear}\label{fig:FEmodel}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that the enclosing `\mbox` is not needed.

[image]

A very similar output is obtained with `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{2in}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2in]{Figure 2a.png}
\subcaption{}
\end{subfigure}\quad
\begin{subfigure}{2in}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{Figure 2b.png}
\subcaption{}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{FE model geometry and boundary conditions; (a)~tension\slash compression,
(b)~simple shear}\label{fig:FEmodel}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In you code snippet, you should put your subcaptions before `\includegraphics`; that is,

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\mbox{\subfigure{\caption{tension/compression}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{Figure 2a.png}}\quad
\subfigure{\caption{simple shear}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{Figure 2b.png} }}
\caption{FE model geometry and boundary conditions} 
%\label{Fig. 2}
\end{figure}
```

Also, many will tell you to use descriptive labels and not numbers.  I ran into this problem awhile ago.  If you place a figure in front of it, you would have to re-index your whole document or you would have `fig 1`, `fig` just placed in between, `fig 2` which is now 3, etc.